# echo in cmd file produces incorrect results

Tags: batch-file

My .cmd file contains:

```
set /A "@zz+=1"
set @zz
echo:"%%@zz%%"
```

Produces:

```
@zz=4
"%@zz%"
```

The `set @zz` shows the variable being properly populated, but `echo` acts as though it is not there.  Curiously, the commands work fine when run from the command prompt.

Comment: why on heaven do you use `%%var%%` instead of `%var%`?

Answer (score 3):

Actually, batch is doing exactly what it's supposed to. While the normal escape character in batch is `^`, you escape `%` in batch scripts like `%%`, so you're telling the script to print a literal `%`, then the string `@zz`, then another literal `%`.

If you really want to echo `%4%`, you need *three* `%` signs on each side: `echo:"%%%@zz%%%"`

This tells batch to print a literal `%`, then the value of `%@zz%`, and then another literal `%`.